# Installing Caffe on Linux Mint: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl

Tags: linux, caffe, pycaffe, linux-mint

Whenever I try installing caffe onto my linux mint machine, I keep getting this:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a 
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

Do any of you know what I might be doing wrong? Thank you for responding.

Comment: Your system is missing hdf5

Answer (score 0):

If you build caffe using make + Makefile.config, add the location of libhdf5.so (can be retrieved by `locate libhdf5.so`), for example
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial`, to `LIBRARY_DIRS` variable.

If you use cmake based build, add this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run ldconfig:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo ldconfig
```